# Access JDBC Connection from jOOQ transaction

Tags: java, jdbc, jooq

Is is possible to access the underlying JDBC connection from within a jOOQ `TransactionRunnable` or `TransactionCallable`?

I'd like to be able to access the PostgreSQL large object API which you get from the connection:

`final LargeObjectManager manager = connection.unwrap(PGConnection.class).getLargeObjectAPI();`

Afaict you only get access to the `ConnectionProvider` which if I call `aquire()` on, doesn't look like I'm going to end up with the same connection for my LOBs as for my statements.

Comment: implement your own connection provider and provide a method to access the last/current/whatever connection?

Comment: That sounds like more work than using plain JDBC which I am doing now. To clarify, the question is if the jOOQ API supports obtaining the current connection and I just cant find it, or it does not support it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In jOOQ 3.7, [#4552](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4552) was implemented to allow for accessing a `Configuration`'s `Connection` via a [`ConnectionRunnable`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ConnectionRunnable.html). For example:

```
DSL.using(configuration)
   .transaction((Configuration c) -> {
       DSL.using(c).connection(connection -> {
           LargeObjectManager manager = connection.unwrap(PGConnection.class).getLargeObjectAPI();
           // ...
       });
   });
```

This API will internally call `acquire()` and `release()`, for convenience, so the following solution is equivalent but more verbose:

```
DSL.using(configuration)
   .transaction((Configuration c) -> {
       Connection connection = c.connectionProvider().acquire();
       try {
           LargeObjectManager manager = connection.unwrap(PGConnection.class).getLargeObjectAPI();
           // ...
       }
       finally {
           c.connectionProvider().release(connection);
       }
   });
```

As the `Connection` is obtained from the "transacted" `Configuration c`, you can be sure that you will access the right `Connection`. Even if you access it several times, it will always be the same as jOOQ internally replaces your own `ConnectionProvider` by a `DefaultConnectionProvider` acting upon the transacted `Connection`

Comment: Thanks Lukas. I'm using 3.5 so I guess I'll stick with using `getSql()` and plain JDBC for the moment, but that's great to know.